# Paypal Braintree Invalid Json

Tags: javascript, json, paypal, braintree

I am trying to use paypal to do subscriptions but I cannot even get a single transaction to work much less subscriptions.... I am using Braintree SDK and i keep getting a javascript error "Invalid Json" when I load the page.

Error says ppxo_unhandled_error.

```
Object
country: "US"
env: "production"
errtype: "[object Error]"
host: "localhost:8081"
lang: "en"
pageID: "5006479a5b"
path: "/secured/welcome.xhtml"
prev_corr_ids: ""
referer: "localhost:8081"
stack: "Error: Invalid json: REALLY LONG KEY THAT I AM DELETING. Correlation 
id: unknown↵    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> 

(https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:14880:51)"
timestamp: 1511409906933
uid: "8354a0522c_ga2dumbvhiydg"
ver: "4.0.166"
windowID: "157fa12bd3"
```

Here is the java code.

```
@Path("/braintree")
public class TestBraintree {
    private static BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway(
            Environment.SANDBOX,
            "myMerchantId",
            "myPublicKey",
            "myPrivateKey"
    );

    @GET
    @Path("/client_token")
    public String getMsg() {
        return gateway.clientToken().generate();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/checkout")
    public String getCheckoutMessage(String json) {
//        String nonceFromTheClient = request .queryParams("payment_method_nonce");
        System.out.println();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Html Code

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.11.0/js/client.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.11.0/js/paypal-checkout.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

                <script>
                    paypal.Button.render({
                        braintree: braintree,
                        client: {
                            production: paypal.request.get('/rest/braintree/client_token'),
                            sandbox: paypal.request.get('/rest/braintree/client_token'),
                        },
                        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'
                        commit: true, // This will add the transaction amount to the PayPal button

                        payment: function (data, actions) {
                            return actions.braintree.create({
                                flow: 'checkout', // Required
                                amount: 10.00, // Required
                                currency: 'USD', // Required
                                enableShippingAddress: true,
                                shippingAddressEditable: false,
                                shippingAddressOverride: {
                                    recipientName: 'Scruff McGruff',
                                    line1: '1234 Main St.',
                                    line2: 'Unit 1',
                                    city: 'Chicago',
                                    countryCode: 'US',
                                    postalCode: '60652',
                                    state: 'IL',
                                    phone: '123.456.7890'
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        onAuthorize: function (payload) {
                            // Submit `payload.nonce` to your server.
                        },
                    }, '#paypal-button-container');
                </script>
</body>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Error`, `Here is the java code.` `Html Code` ... but the error is in parsing JSON ... what does the JSON look like?

Comment: Apparently paypal.request.get() is not working. I used jquery to get the value and then set it and it does not have an issue. But still am not sure how to do subscriptions now.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paypal Braintree Subscription Payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449758/paypal-braintree-subscription-payments)